# Run powershell in php

Tags: php, powershell

I have a very small program which I want to execute upon button press . In html it contains an button with an image and when i press the button it should call my php script which has powershell and has to be executed . But it doesnt add the printer through the manual command attached is working.

My html code here is as follows :

```
<html>
<head>
<form action="rabbit.php" method="POST">
<input type="image" src="image/GOOGLE.jpg" value="submit" alt="Submit" width="78" 
height="78">
</head>
</html>
```

Php code :

```
 <?php 
  echo powershell.exe (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\\file-computer-01\IN-SEA-GOOGLE");
 ?>
```

Even I tried in this way and it just echo's the command :

```
 <?php
 $psPath = 'c:\\Windows\\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\powershell.exe';
 $psDIR = "c:\\wamp\\www\\printer\\scripts\\";
 $psScript = "rabbit.ps1";
 $runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
 $runCMD = $psPath.  "&". $runScript;
 echo $runCMD;
 ?>
```

Moreover I get the output as in the page as :

> c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&c:\wamp\www\printer\scripts\rabbit.ps1

My powershell code contains like this :

> (New-Object -ComObject
>   WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\file-computer-01\IN-SEA-GOOGLE")

If I execute the direct powershell script it works but not via PHP .

In both the cases, it just gives echo and doesnt add the printer .

Any ideas or suggestions please.... as i new to php struggling a lot to figure it out this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It just echo's the command because that's what your code tells it to do :)
Try replacing

```
echo $runCMD;
```

with

```
echo exec($runCMD);
```

PS also you will probably need to add the ExecutionPolicy directive to your command, because by default script execution is prohibited. So your command should be:

```
<?php
$psPath = 'c:\\Windows\\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\powershell.exe';
$psDIR = "c:\\wamp\\www\\printer\\scripts\\";
$psScript = "rabbit.ps1";
$runCMD = $psPath. ' -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned '.$psDIR.$psScript;

exec($runCMD, $out);
echo join($out);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want PHP's [system](http://php.net/system) function. Or perhaps its [popen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)...